# Storing multiple user inputs into a .txt and .bin C#

Tags: c#

I have here a piece of code for my class where I am entering values that are being written into a .txt and .bin file.

My problems are that my .txt file ends up being empty and my .bin file is not writing in binary.

I believe I have written and closed the .bin file and .txt correctly but my inputs are not being stored correctly

Here is my code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string numberOfStudents, studentName, studentHeight, studentWeight;
            int studentInput = 0, height;
            bool numberOutput, heightOutput, weightOutput;
            double weight; 




            Console.Write("Enter number of students: ");
            numberOfStudents = Console.ReadLine();
            numberOutput = int.TryParse(numberOfStudents, out studentInput);


            if (numberOutput == true)
            {  
                    if (studentInput <= 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Number of students must be a positive integer (greater than 0)!");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for (int i = 1; i <= studentInput; i++)
                        {
                            Console.Write("Enter student name: ");
                            studentName = Console.ReadLine();

                            Console.Write("Enter student height in centimetres: ");
                            studentHeight = Console.ReadLine();
                            heightOutput = int.TryParse(studentHeight, out height);

                            Console.Write("Enter student weight in kilograms: ");
                            studentWeight = Console.ReadLine();
                            weightOutput = double.TryParse(studentWeight, out weight);

                        try
                        {
                            StreamWriter outputFile;

                            outputFile = new StreamWriter("test.txt");
                            outputFile.Write(numberOfStudents + studentName + studentHeight + studentWeight);
                            outputFile.Close();
                        }

                        catch (System.IO.IOException exc)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("There was an error!: " + exc.Message);
                        }

                        try
                        {
                            FileStream outputFile = new FileStream("outFile.bin", FileMode.Create);
                            BinaryWriter BinFile = new BinaryWriter(outputFile);
                            BinFile.Write(studentName + " " + studentHeight + " " + studentWeight);
                            BinFile.Close();
                        }

                        catch (System.IO.IOException exc)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("There was an error!: " + exc.Message);
                        }

                        FileStream dataOutput = new FileStream("Database", FileMode.Create);
                        BinaryWriter databaseFile = new BinaryWriter(dataOutput);

                        StreamWriter textOutput = new StreamWriter("outText.txt");

                        databaseFile.Write(studentName + " " + studentHeight + " " + studentWeight);

                        databaseFile.Close();
                        textOutput.Close();
                    }
                    }


            }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there but there are a few issues with the code and it could be tidied up a little.

1. You are creating 3 files: outFile.bin, outText.txt, and test.txt. No data/text is written to `outFile.txt`, it is opened then closed a few lines later. Look in `test.txt`, it will have the last students data (see next point).
2. You are writing the files in a loop, which is overwriting the data, so only the last users data is being written to the file. Use `outputFile = new StreamWriter("test.txt", true)`  this overload of `StreamWriter` will allow you to choose to append to the file (true) or overwrite (false).
3. I'd recommend looking at the `using()` statement when writing to file or any class that implements `IDisposable`. For example, when opening the StreamWriter you could do `using (var outputFile = new StreamWriter("test.txt", true)) { }`.  This ensures the streamwriter is closed and disposed by the garbage collector, (For example, you are not closing the `dataOutput` file stream, if this was in a `using(){}` block it would automatically be handled for you)
4. This could be refactored into using just one `try {} catch {}` block, you do not need a separate try/catch for each time you write to a file.

From the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binarywriter?view=netframework-4.7.2), the `BinaryWriter` class

> Writes primitive types in binary to a stream and supports writing strings in a specific encoding.

So, the binary writer is writing in binary, but the data it's writing are strings. It could easily write `int`, `double`, `bool`, etc.

Here's the code in your try/catch blocks tidied up a bit (this only creates test.txt and outFile.bin):

```
try
{
    // will open or create file in 'append' mode
    using (var outputFile = new StreamWriter("test.txt", true))
    {
        outputFile.Write($"{numberOfStudents}, {studentName}, {studentHeight},{studentWeight}");
        outputFile.Write(Environment.NewLine);
    }
    using (BinaryWriter databaseFile = new BinaryWriter(File.Open("outFile.bin", FileMode.Append)))
    {                                 
        databaseFile.Write(studentName + " " + studentHeight + " " + studentWeight);
    }
}
catch (System.IO.IOException exc)
{
    Console.WriteLine("There was an error!: " + exc.Message);
}
```